# I want to check answer and display it on HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new on Javascript coding. I'm creating a web page for surveys or testing by myself.

Now here is my code;

```
<form id="q1form">
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="q1"> true
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="q2"> false
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()"> try </button>

function myFunction(){
   var form = document.getElementById('q1form'),
   s1 = form['question1'],
    n;
    for (n = 0; n < s1.length; n++) {
    if (s1[n].checked) {
        var soru1= parseInt(s1[n].value);
       }
}
if(soru1==1){ 
    document.writeln("Your answer is correct!"); 
}
else{
    document.wirteln("Your answer is not correct");
}
}
```

In this code I want to display "Your answer is correct!" or other answer near the 'try' button. I can display answer with window.alert but I want to do it near button, in same page. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Never use docuemnt.write after load. Instead use some element's innerHTML

Comment: so a developer can answer all questions as correct! (Inspect Element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a div next to the button `<span id="feedback"></span>` and then insert the feedback into that div:

```
var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
feedback.innerHTML = "Your answer is correct!";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I have one problem. When I click the button in page, it sends browser to .../Desktop/odev.html?question1=1. 
I can see the feedback but button refreshes page in like miliseconds.

Comment: Try `<button onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">`

Comment: Use a span instead of a div because it will display it beside the button instead of below

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
<form id="q1form">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="q1">true
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="q2">false
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">try</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(btn) {
        var form = document.getElementById('q1form'),
            s1   = form['question1'],
            p    = document.createElement('p'),
            txt,
            n;
        for (n = 0; n < s1.length; n++) {
            if (s1[n].checked) {
                var soru1 = parseInt(s1[n].value);
            }
        }

        if (soru1 == 1) {
            txt = "Your answer is correct!"
        } else {
            txt = "Your answer is not correct";
        }
        var oldP = document.getElementById('response');
        if (oldP) oldP.parentNode.removeChild(oldP);
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
        p.id = "response";
        btn.parentNode.insertBefore(p, btn.nextSibling);
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6W83L/)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
function myFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById('q1form'),
        output = document.getElementById('output'),
        s1 = form['question1'],
        n;
    for (n = 0; n < s1.length; n++) {
        if (s1[n].checked) {
            var soru1 = parseInt(s1[n].value);
        }
    }
    output.innerHTML = soru1 === 1 ? "Your answer is correct!"
                                   : "Your answer is not correct" ;
}
```

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBahE/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  <form id="q1form">
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="q1"> true
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="q2"> false
  </form>
  <button onclick="myFunction()"> try </button>
  <span id="demo"></span>

  function myFunction(){
  var form = document.getElementById('q1form'),
  s1 = form['question1'],
  n;
  for (n = 0; n < s1.length; n++) {
  if (s1[n].checked) {
    var soru1= parseInt(s1[n].value);
   }
  }
  if(soru1==1){ 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Your answer is correct";
  }
 else{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Your answer is not correct";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Use a span, not a p, because then it will display it beside the button instead of below.